# Sort C# array while adding numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have this array and I want that every time the user inputs a number, the program immediately makes the sort. How can I do that? For example, if I input 6 and then 3, immediately takes the 3 to the first position. And then if I put 2, immediately take it to the first position and sort the others (2,3,6). Then if I put 1, takes it to the first position, sorting the others(1,2,3,6) and so on

```
        int[] a = new int[5] ;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

Comment: Why not use a collection that sorts for you like [`SortedSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=netframework-4.8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @juharr suggest you can use System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

  var list = new SortedSet<int>();
  int count = 5;

  for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

  foreach (int item in list)
    Console.WriteLine(item);

  Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

add the numbers to a list and call list.sort()

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 6, 3 };
list.Sort();
```